# Can't dynamically add value to hidden input Sprout field

Tags: plugins, form, field, plugin-sproutforms, custom-fieldtype

I'm trying to add a hidden input with Sprout forms and Sprout fields but I can't dynamically add a value to the input attribute.

I have a custom form template in `craft/templates/_forms/field.html` in which I have the following code for the hidden field:

```
{%- set name = field.handle is defined ? field.handle : null %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ settings.value }}">
```

This now returns whatever value I put into the 'Hidden Field Value' input in the form builder in Craft, but if I put any dynamic data in there, e.g. `{{ craft.request.path }}` (which is also the placeholder text), I get the same literal string back: "{{ craft.request.path }}". I've also tried with single braces, as I read that this might be the correct syntax, but I get the same result.

Eventually, I am wanting to set the value to `{{ entry.title }}`. I read that I need to add this to my template to be able to access non-global variables `{% do craft.sproutForms.addFieldVariables({ entry: entry }) %}` - does this go in the entry template just before the form, or in the form template. I get an error saying `Variable "entry" does not exist` if I put it in the form template so I'm guessing it goes in the entry template.

Comment: The `addFieldVariables` line should go outside of your form tag. It makes the variables you are passing to it available in a more global way so that when the form is processed they can be accessed.